# How to disable Dell trackpad when mouse plugged in to usb port?

Tags: usb, mouse, dell, touchpad, trackpad

When in Windows 7 I have the option to have the touchpad automatically be disabled when a usb mouse in plugged in. Then when the mouse in unplugged the touchpad automatically becomes enabled. There is even a light at the top of the touchpad the comes on when it is in disabled mode! Is there a way to duplicate this functionality under Ubuntu 13.04? (I have a Dell Inspiron 15r with Hybrid AMD/Intel graphics.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I automatically deactivate my touchpad when a USB-mouse is connected?](http://askubuntu.com/q/58584) or [How to disable the notebook Touch Pad when a wireless USB mouse is connected](http://askubuntu.com/q/6206) or [Disable laptop touchpad when wacom tablet is plugged?](http://askubuntu.com/q/240768) It should apply to disabling a touchpad with wired USB pointing devices also. Some more alternative solutions there would be good, but `gpointing-device-settings` seems to still be available for installation in current versions of Ubuntu.